# Ajax in a settings page (update_option is undefined)

Tags: ajax

I'm making a request to my plugin's php file via ajax and it's supposed to save some data with update_option(), but php throws an error:

```
Call to undefined function update_option()
```

I'm guessing that when I call my php file with ajax WP doesn't load it's functions... or something?

Cheers

Answer (score 24):

Don't send AJAX to your PHP file directly.  Instead, use WordPress' built-in AJAX functions <sup>1)</sup>.  You can register an AJAX callback from your plugin, and WordPress will route requests to your plugin file for you.

For example, this code will register a callback called "wpa_49691":

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_wpa_49691', 'wpa_49691_callback' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_wpa_49691', 'wpa_49691_callback' );
function wpa_49691_callback() {
    // Do whatever you need with update_option() here.
    // You have full access to the $_POST object.
}
```

Then, you post whatever data you need, just specify `action` in the object:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        var data = {
            action: 'wpa_49691',
            my_var: 'my_data'
        };

        jQuery.post( ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
            // handle response from the AJAX request.
        });
    });
</script>
```

This script will post your data to the server.  Inside the server callback, you'll see `$_POST['my_var'] = 'my_data'`.

For further reading, check out:

- [The Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins)
- [WordPress and AJAX](http://wpajax.com/) - Free ebook on the topic

<sup>1) Use `wp_register_script( $handle );` » `wp_enqueue_script( $handle )` » `wp_localize_script( $handle );` - the last one to move php stuff into a js-var that can be access inside your AJAX script.</sup>

Comment: This is the way to do it